# Can VS Code detect nonexistent functions in PHP?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a PHP project and wondering if VS Code can be set up to detect references to functions that don't exist.

```
class Client {
    public function user()
    {
        return new User();
    }
}

class Lib {
    public static function getClient() {
        return new Client();
    }
}

$client = Lib::getClient();
$response = $client->users();
```

As you can see in the code above, the call to users should be user instead. I don't see anything visual in VS Code that would show what's wrong here. PhpStorm has this feature. Is this something that is available in VS Code somewhere? I tried installing some PHP extensions. Here's a list of the ones I installed.

[image: list of extensions]

Comment: Find php extension in vs code

Comment: @Rohit.007 I installed several PHP extensions. Still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I haven't found a solution.